# Como realizar uma condição no array para verificar se vários elementos existem ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte *array* como exemplo:

```
var a = ['view', 'edit', 'insert']
```

E preciso da seguinte condição:

```
a.includes('view') // esperado: true, resultado: true
a.includes('view', 'teste') // esperado: false, resultado: true
```

No segundo exemplo, o valor retornado é `true`, pois o valor `view` é encontrado, mas eu gostaria que fosse retornado `false`, igual a uma condição `AND`

Tentei algo com `indexOf()`, mas cheguei no mesmo resultado.

O que posso fazer?

Obs: Eu posso ter mais de dois parâmetros para comparar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma versão eficiente:

```js
function includesTwo(array, one, two) {
    let achou = false;
    for (const item of array) {
        if (item == one || item == two) {
            if (achou) return true;
            achou = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const a = ['view', 'edit', 'insert'];
console.log(includesTwo(a, 'view', 'edit'));
console.log(includesTwo(a, 'view', 'teste'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/IncludesTwo.js).

Esta forma varre o *array* apenas uma vez, além de ser mais eficiente por usar menos abstrações, mas essa parte nem é importante. Quando você manda um item ser buscado em um *array* uma vez e depois outra vez pode ter o gasto dobrado. Assim está varrendo uma vez e acha os dois dados de uma vez só. Não se engane `includes()` e `every()` é um `for` abstraído, ele tem que varrer, potencialmente, toda a coleção.

Tem um detalhe que não pode ter valores repetidos no *array*. Se isso não pode ser garantido fica um pouco mais complicado:

```js
function includesTwo(array, one, two) {
    let achouOne = false;
    let achouTwo = false;
    for (const item of array) {
        if (item == one) {
            if (achouTwo) return true;
            achouOne = true;
        }
        if (item == two) {
            if (achouOne) return true;
            achouTwo = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const a = ['view', 'view', 'edit'];
console.log(includesTwo(a, 'view', 'edit'));
console.log(includesTwo(a, 'view', 'teste'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/IncludesTwo2.js).

Dá para generalizar para vários itens se quiser, eu fiz o que a pergunta pedia. Para fazer para qualquer quantidade de itens teria que ter um laço percorrendo os valores a serem buscados. Quanto mais mais itens forem adicionando a distância da eficiência vai ficando maior. Com dois valores a serem concatenados na busca o ganho é bom, já que pode reduzir o custo pela metade, mas em uma lista de valores grande o ganho pode ser absurdamente grande, inclusive o uso de `includes()` e `every()` pode se tornar inviável já tem complexidade exponencial em relação ao valores buscados, enquanto que a solução do laço simples que eu dei tem complexidade linear em relação aos valores.

O caminho das pedras foi dado nesse último. Você precisa de uma variável de controle para cada valor que vai buscar. Como fazer isso se você pode ter vários valores? Simples, coloca em uma coleção. Pode usar um *array* com a chave sendo cada valor iniciando em `false` e mudando `true` quando achar aquele.

Answer (score 9):

Utilizando o método `includes`, você só pode verificar se um elemento existe por vez, já que somente o primeiro argumento pode ser utilizado para esse fim. [Consulte a documentação para saber mais.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

Se você quiser verificar se vários elementos existem em um array, pode utilizar o operador AND (`&&`) explicitamente. Assim:

```js
const arr = ['view', 'edit', 'insert'];

console.log(
  arr.includes('view') && arr.includes('test')
); // false
```

Uma outra opção é criar uma função `includesAll`, que encapsula essa lógica:

```js
function includesAll(arr, ...items) {
  for (const item of items) {
    if (!arr.includes(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const arr = ['view', 'edit', 'insert'];
console.log(includesAll(arr, 'view', 'edit')); // true
console.log(includesAll(arr, 'view', 'teste')); // false
```

O problema em utilizar `includes` (ou `indexOf`) assim é que, para cada item que você quer buscar, teoricamente, uma busca completa no array é realizada. Assim, se você quiser verificar a existência de 4 elementos em um array de 100 elementos, no pior dos cenários, você realizará 400 buscas (`4 * 100`), isto é, 100 buscas para cada um dos 4 elementos. Consulte o [algoritmo do `includes` na especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) para entender melhor.

Uma forma de otimizar isso é utilizar a estrutura de dados `Set`:

```js
function includesAll(arr, items) {
  const set = new Set(arr);
  for (const item of items) {
    if (!set.has(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5];
console.log(includesAll(arr, [1, 2, 3, 4])); // true
console.log(includesAll(arr, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // true
console.log(includesAll(arr, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // false
```

Essa última solução, embora ligeiramente mais custosa em memória (porque também tem que manter o `Set`), é extremamente mais eficiente que a apresentada anteriormente, haja vista que tem complexidade assintótica linear. Nesse sentido, comparando com as 400 iterações exigidas pelo algoritmo anterior, este último exigiria apenas 104.

Comment: Nada melhor do que o bom, velho e garantido IF() bem usado. Parabéns, do meu ponto de vista seu primeiro código `arr.includes('view') && arr.includes('test')` resolve, é o que sempre deveria ser, sem exagerar e sem ficar criando metodologias ou então achar que ES6 em diante mudará 100% da linguagem. Viva o simples que funciona bem :D (ps: para retrocompatibilidade sugiro o `indexOf() !== 1`)

Answer (score 8):

É possível usar a função `every`. Ela verifica se todas as condições são verdadeiras e retorna `true`. Caso alguma retorne `false`, retorna `false`.

```js
let a = ['view', 'edit', 'insert'];

console.log(['view', 'teste'].every(b => a.includes(a)))

console.log(['view', 'insert'].every(b => a.includes(b)))
```

O que fizemos no caso foi basicamente aplicar a função `includes` em cada um dos itens de `a`.

Podemos também  criamos uma função para facilitar o trabalho. Como a outra resposta já ensina a criação da função, preferi usar `Array.prototype` para o próprio array possuir o método que faça essa verificação.

Veja:

```js
Array.prototype.includesAll = function (...args) {
    return args.every(item => this.includes(item));
}

let a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];


console.log(a.includesAll('a')); // true
console.log(a.includesAll('a', 'b')); // true
console.log(a.includesAll('a', 'b', 'd')); // false
```

**Nota**: Apesar de alterar o prototype diretamente, é importante lembrar que em alguns casos isso pode causar alguns problemas dependendo do Browser e afins, por exemplo, se essa função no futuro fosse criada nativamente no `Array`.

Answer (score -2):

Cara é possível realizar de uma forma mais flexível, validando se o array tem as propriedades sem colocar uma condição:

```js
const arr = ["CNPJ", "Nome", "IE", "Endereço", "Estado", "País"];

function includesValues(array: string[], arrayValues: string[]) {
  let result = false;
  for (const value of arrayValues) {
    result = array.some((arr: string) => arr === value);
  }
  return result;
}

if (includesValues(arr, ["CNPJ", "Nome", "IE", "Endereço"])) {
  // do something
  console.log('Olá, mundo!');
}
```

Dessa forma, independente do que tenha dentro do array, as propriedades que você mencionar serão validadas corretamente.